# Clique - too few transaction inside a limited block

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, poa

i have got the problem that my private node doesn't put all transactions that would be possible inside a block.

Concret i am running a private poa node which should have a fixed blocksize. Therefore i started the node by using: `geth --targetgaslimit 210000 --networkid XXXX --mine --datadir "." --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "XXXX" --port "XXXX" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net --unlock 0 --password XXXX --ipcpath "~/.ethereum/geth.ipc"` (XXXX are here just placeholder)

The private node runs sucessfull and mines block and put transactions inside the blocks. But therebye not all transactions that would be possible are put into a block. For example i have got 42 waiting transactions with a size of 21.0000 so that 10 transactions should be put inside a block. But only 6 transactions ar put inside a block.

I don't understand why only 6 and not 10 transactions are put inside a block. Can it be because of the targetgaslimit that i have set?

Comment: What is the block gas limit? The parameter `targetgaslimit` make the limit go up or down until the limit is reached but it can take several blocks until that point.

Comment: Are you sending all transaction from the same account? What is your `gas` set in the transaction? What is the actual gasLimit of the latest block (Ismael's question).

Comment: The actual block gasLimit is 210.000 gas. I sended all transactions from the same account. Concrete i let a account send himself money and used therefore the command eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:eth.accounts[0],value:web3.toWei(1,"Wei")}). After reading ivicaa's question i added a gas value eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:eth.accounts[0],value:web3.toWei(1,"Wei"),gas:21000}) and now there are 10 transactions per block as expected. Now my question is, what does the gas value stand for and why were there only 6 transactions per block when i didn't set it.